# How to automatically download a PDF file from a JSF page

Tags: python, selenium, download

I need to automate some pdf documents downloads with python and selenium. The preferences of chrome and firefox are already done to automate download, but I have a problem with this especific website, it does not download the document automatically, it opens a new tab

> website: http://sistemas.sefaz.ma.gov.br/certidoes/jsp/emissaoCertidaoNegativa/emissaoCertidaoNegativa.jsf
>   Select CPF/CNPJ and use this number to access the document 22977333000108.

After filling the form I get the document in a new tab with the same url like on the screenshot [Documment Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaOIA.png) (Sorry, had to hide the documments numbers). If I manually download it and rename as PDF file it works fine.

How can I download it as a pdf file with selenium?

My code is like:

```
 urlForm = 'https://sistemas.sefaz.ma.gov.br/certidoes/jsp/emissaoCertidaoNegativa/emissaoCertidaoNegativa.jsf'
 #loading firefox webdriver with preferences
 driver = loadDriver( urlForm ) 

 #form filled

 # Clicking submit button
 btnSubmit = driver.find_element_by_id('form1:j_id28')
 btnSubmit.click()
 time.sleep(3)     

 # switch to new tab
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Then I try to download the file with glob like this:

```
certidoes = glob.glob('emissaoCertidaoNegativa*')
print(certidoes)
```

but it prints something like:

> [emissaoCertidaoNegativa.jsf;jsessionid=44297D6C88452FC479FC0E94013D3C0A]

and when I try to rename it to pdf I get an empty file... can someone help?

Comment: I can't open the link

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which
>   must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be
>   either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like
>   ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken
>   symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).

so you have to specify the path to the file.

***Example:***

lets say we have two `output.txt` files in two different directories:

- `C:\\Test\\output.txt`
- `C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\output.txt`

then if we try the following code:

```
print(glob.glob('C:\\Test\\output.txt', recursive=True))
print(glob.glob('C:\\**\\output.txt', recursive=True))
print(glob.glob('C:\\**\\output.txt'))
print(glob.glob('output.txt'))
```

output will be:

```
['C:\\Test\\output.txt']
['C:\\test\\output.txt', 'C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\output.txt']
['C:\\test\\output.txt']
[]
```

So you have to specify the path to the directory, where your file is saved. You can use `**`, but as documentation says:

> Note Using the “**” pattern in large directory trees may consume an
>   inordinate amount of time.

Comment: Sorry, it returns in a list, I will edit. The donwload path is already especified. The problem is it is downloading that file, not just a .jsf

Comment: could you please provide a working link to the website/document ?

Comment: a general link to the website I can get, but what have I do to reproduce the page you are getting with the document?

Comment: use this 22977333000108 cnpj number to acess the document page, but maybe the service is unavailable now

Comment: could you see the documment?